# Apple HTML Slideshow, missing bevel_top.giv and bevel_l.gif

Tags: web, http-status-code-404, slideshow

After exporting a "Apple-Slideshow" ,
`bevel_top.gif` and `bevel_l.gif` are missing from **SlideShow_assets** folder.

What to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stated [here in the apple forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/504590) ,

you might just recreate them by rotating others ...

Imagemagick Example:

```sh
convert  bevel_r.gif -rotate 180 bevel_l.gif
convert bevel_bot.gif -rotate 180 bevel_top.gif
```

Regards